# In PowerBI refresh succeeding on PowerBI desktop, but failing when refreshing on the webpage

Tags: powerbi

I created a report in Powerbi desktop. The dataset is a view from a table and I used the Import method and not DirectQuery. There is a lot of data. So when I do a refresh on the PowerBi desktop, it does the refresh but takes a while. When I published my report, and scheduled a daily refresh, the daily refresh fails with the following error

```
Data source type: SQL 
Data source error: Microsoft SQL: Query timeout expired
```

How can I olve this. I have tried deleting and publishing the report again and again. I also checked the data credentials field in the schedule refresh tab.

Comment: Direct Query wouldn't work for me because it doesn't support a lot of modeling. Also I do not want the database to be pinged everytime the report is used.

Comment: Please define "a lot of data" - # rows, also size in MB of PBI Desktop file.

Comment: The size of the Desktop PBI report is 85,417k.

Comment: The size of the Desktop PBI report is 85,417k and the number of rows are 9428542

Answer (score 1):

I would open the report file in Power BI Desktop and make these changes:

- Navigate to the "file" menu (top-left) **/ Options and settings / Settings**

  - Under **Current File / Data Load / Parallel Loading ...**, check the **Enable parallel loading ...** option
  - Under **Current File / Privacy**, choose **Ignore the Privacy Levels ...**

Hopefully that's enough to get you over the line.

If not then I would work on speeding the query design.  From your error message it sounds like the generated query is very slow to start returning rows.  I'd try to move any Filter, Group By or Choose/Remove Column steps up the **Applied Steps** list so they have an impact early and reduce the load on your database server.

Comment: The enable parallel loading option was already set. And yes my view query is slow to start returning rows, but I cannot move those steps to the applied steps because of some constraints in pbi.

Comment: Then I would work with your DBAs to improve the SQL query performance. They should be able to run a Profiler Trace to catch the SELECT statements generated by PBI, then tune for that with indexes etc.